# Reading and storing date from file with different line format

Tags: file, parsing, format, line

How do I read a file in which each line has a different format. I have a file that looks like this

```
James 0 14 12  
Lucy    
Lucas 0 45   
Alice 87 23 10 23    
etc...
```

And I have to store the values to use them later. How would I do that.

If each line had the same format I would use `getline()`, but can I use it here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `stringstream` to help separate out your values once you get each line. For example:

```
std::string line = "James 0 14 12";
std::istringstream ss(line);
std::string piece;
while(ss >> piece)
    std::cout << piece << '\n';
```

will print out:

```
James
0
14
12
```

You could add each piece to whatever data structure you want.